# Comments disabled on proposed change that deletes a topic

Tags: bug, comments, documentation, documentation-proposals

Before I approved [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/26152), I was unable to comment on the proposal. This doesn't seem to be the intended behavior. I do know that:

- This proposal handles an improvement request submitted by me.
- This proposal was previously approved by another user

Comment: Reproduced by reviewing a topic-deletion proposal that purported to handle an improvement request I'd raised: no comment UI.